# Breaking feedback resistor

Tags: feedback

[image]

I need to find the input/output impedances of this circuit (both open-loop and closed loop). I'm not sure how to deal with the Rf resistor as it lies in the middle.

I was thinking to use the Miller Theorem and do this,
[image]

Would that be correcT?

Comment: Open loop, the Rin is 1/gm of M1.

Comment: `@analogsystemsrf How come you ignored Rf? I know it's part of the feedback loop but when you break the feedback, Rf should go on one of the sides?

Comment: If 1/gm << Rf, then we may chose to ignore it..